# How to write file size in kB to text file?

Tags: vbscript

I have my VBscript which will convert the data from specific folder (e.g. C:) to text file with file sizes. My problem here is, my file size is converting to bytes instead of kb. Any idea how i can modify this script to get the exact file size in kb? Below is my VBscript:

```
Dim fso
Dim ObjFolder
Dim ObjOutFile
Dim ObjFiles
Dim ObjFile

'Creating File System Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Getting the Folder Object
Set ObjFolder = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folder A")

'Creating an Output File to write the File sizes
Set ObjOutFile = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\User\Desktop\IDENTIFIYING ZERO FILE SIZE KB.txt")

'Getting the list of Files
Set ObjFiles = ObjFolder.Files

'Writing sizes and Path of each File to Output File
For Each ObjFile In ObjFiles
    ObjOutFile.WriteLine(ObjFile.size & String(50 - Len(ObjFile.size), " ") & ObjFile.Path)
Next

ObjOutFile.Close
```

Answer (score 4):

Divide the size by 1024 to get it in kB and round the value to the appropriate number of digits (e.g. 2):

```
For Each ObjFile In ObjFiles
  size = Round(ObjFile.size / 1024, 2)
  ObjOutFile.WriteLine size & String(50 - Len(size), " ") & ObjFile.Path
Next
```

Comment: Hi Ansgar, thank you so much to explain and share your script. It works well! :-)

Comment: Im sorry to tick "this answer is not useful". It is very useful actually. I wrongly read it..