# Grab file name from file list, if file size greater than 1MB do copy

Tags: vbscript

I have been set out by the following task by one of my managers at work:

We have a database of images for all our clothing styles and colours. For each type of clothing and for each colour we have 3 images. 2 of them are low resolution images and 1 of them is a high resolution image.

We need to copy the high res image for each style and colour from the old database which is made up of sub folders into one folder therefore ignoring the folder structure.

I have come across this Visual Basic script which is quite close to what I need but requires a few tweaks, as I am not really experienced with VB scripts I was hoping I could get some help here over at SO.

What I need to script to be tweaked to is:
-The script to read image names from a list (filelist.txt) (if possible without requiring to add the path for each image to the list, just the name and the extension which is .jpg)
-The script only needs to grab images if the size is greater than 1MB.
-The script to copy the images from sub-folders without keeping the folder structure.

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated, explanations behind the tweaks and any guidance will also be kind but not required.

Here is the script that I have so far. The paths are temporary as I was playing around with the script.

```
Option Explicit

' The source path for the copy operation.
Const strSourceFolder = "C:\Users\Cou Rou\Desktop\Old database"

' The target path for the copy operation.
Const strTargetFolder = "C:\Users\Cou Rou\Desktop\New database"

' The list of files to copy. Should be a text file with one file on each row. No paths - just file name.
Const strFileList = "C:\Users\Cou Rou\Desktop\Old database\filelist.txt"

' Should files be overwriten if they already exist? TRUE or FALSE.
Const blnOverwrite = FALSE

Dim objFSO
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Const ForReading = 1
Dim objFileList
Set objFileList = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileList, ForReading, False)

Dim strFileToCopy, strSourceFilePath, strTargetFilePath
On Error Resume Next
Do Until objFileList.AtEndOfStream
    ' Read next line from file list and build filepaths
    strFileToCopy = objFileList.Readline
    strSourceFilePath = objFSO.BuildPath(strSourceFolder, strFileToCopy)
    strTargetFilePath = objFSO.BuildPath(strTargetFolder, strFileToCopy)

    ' Copy file to specified target folder.
    Err.Clear
    objFSO.CopyFile strSourceFilePath, strTargetFilePath, blnOverwrite
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        ' File copied successfully
    Else
        ' Error copying file
        Wscript.Echo "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & "). Copying " & strFileToCopy
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: Thats not VB.NET code.

Comment: You can start from here, try to do it yourself, and if you have problems, post your new code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623883/how-to-write-file-size-in-kb-to-text-file

Comment: What didn't you like from the comments/answers in your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44022952/batch-file-to-copy-files-from-folderssub-folders-using-a-file-list-only-if-file) with the same topic?

Comment: 1) That was regarding a batch script
2) After getting some answers I started tweaking the code I already had and got nowhere.
3) The complete code I received in the answer does nothing.
4) I moved on to VisualBasic as the coding seems a bit more easier to read and understand.